# C++: Using boost lambda to get maximum values in a std::tr1::unordered_map

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, lambda

I have  a `std::tr1::unordered_map<int, A> map;` where  A is a class with a member variable (int x).

I would like to find the key i in map such that map[i].x is maximum.

I know that I can write a functor to go with std::max_element. How do I do this instead, using
boost lambda (I am trying to learn it) ? I do not have C++0x.

As an added question, what if I had class A defined as below:

class A {
 int x;
 int y;
};

And I wanted to find the maximum w.r.t x (if that maximum was 0, find the maximum wrt to y).
Again, one solution would be to iterate over the tuples of the map (keeping both
maxima in memory). Is there a way to modify max_element to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boost.lambda uses boost.bind to access member variables. It comes up a bit wordy:

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<int, A> map_t;
map_t m;

A max_a = std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(),
                bind(&A::x, bind(&map_t::value_type::second, _1))
              < bind(&A::x, bind(&map_t::value_type::second, _2))
         )->second;
```

test: https://ideone.com/V6SZL

You may save half the headache with boost.range

```
A max_a = *boost::max_element(m | map_values, bind(&A::x, _1) < bind(&A::x, _2));
```

But in practice, I think, a functor would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just starting to learn Boost.Lambda, now is the perfect time to forget it exists and learn [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/phoenix/index.html) instead. Boost.Phoenix is the replacement for Boost.Lambda and is **considerably** more powerful, and often more succinct:

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<int, A> map_t;
map_t m;

int i = std::max_element(
    m.begin(),
    m.end(),
    bind(&A::x, at_c<1>(_1)) < bind(&A::x, at_c<1>(_2))
)->first;
A& max_a = m[i];
```

Note that Boost.Phoenix v2 is currently a sublibrary of [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html), but in 1.47.0 Boost.Phoenix v3 is slated to be released as a proper standalone Boost library.